# Load file from Sample File Directory named "images"

Tags: directory, imageview, load, uri

I have this simple structure

[image]

Now I should load `11.png` to ImageView from URI.
How do I do this?

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("What should be here???")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you Are New To Android?

Its Better To  move the Image File to Drawable Folder and and Set Image View From the Drawable. You Can Use BatchDrawableImport Plugin in Android Studio to Import multiple Drawable Files

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImageName);
```

Or Move the File to Assets Folder and Using Assets Manager You Can Achieve the Solution

```
    AssetManager manager = getAssets();

    // Read a Bitmap from Assets
    try {
        InputStream open = manager.open("icon.png");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I am new. Thank you for your reply. I know how to use Assets. I have 10 png-files, and after pressing a button, ImageView should load a random file. To be honest, I don't know how to put a lot of files to Assets folder. Well... I really need to load files from sampledata folder. Is it possible?

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-assetmanager-example-to-load-image-from-assets-folder

Comment: Asset folder ids similar to the SameSample data folder.